# Justification for the intuitive definition of simply connected spaces

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

A space $ X $ is simply connected if $ \pi_1(X) $ is trivial, but there exists also an intuitive definition of such space that demand the space to be "without holes".

My question is how to show that the formal definition actually models the intuitive one?

For example, how to show, using an elementary algebraic topology (like in chapter 9 in munkers), that if we take a connected subspace $ X \subset \mathbb{R}^2 $, such that every point $ x \in S^1 $ is a limit point of $ X $ and $ B(0,1) \cap X = \emptyset $ than the space isn't simply connected (make we can extend this result and take a simply connected space instead of $ S^1 $).

I'm looking for a more techical understanding of it so that's OK to assume that $ S^1 \subset X $, if that's making the mathematics cleaner.

Comment: There is a notion of being able to "shrink" any loop (closed path) to a point in a simply connected space.  Do you consider this "intuitive" or "formal" in comparison to the idea of "no holes"?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't though about it. That's another deifition of simply connected which is strongly relate to the formal definition, but I feel that I don't really why that's equivalent to the "no holes" definition.

Comment: Well, the "no holes" definition is really not a formal definition, and has to be taken in a very liberal interpretation to match with "simply connected".  For example, the surface of a torus ("doughnut") is without local ("small") holes; a wanderer on that surface might easily fail to notice the holes as such (because they appear in the "large" structure).

Comment: I know the problem with a formal definition of holes, that's why I choose a space in the plane. I don't understrand also why the torus doesn't satistify the "no holes" definition: every doughnut (torus) is acctually with a hole, the formal definition of that hole is complicated than in 2 dimensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Let's assume $S^1 \subset X$. Denote by $\gamma$ the loop.

$$ \gamma : [0,1] \longrightarrow  S^1 \subset X \\   t \longmapsto e^{2\pi i t}$$

Let $i: X \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 -\{0\}$, be the inclusion map. We know that $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^2-{0})$ is generated by the class $[i \circ\gamma]$. Hence $i_{*} : \pi_1(X) \rightarrow\pi_1\left(\mathbb{R}^2-\{0\}\right)$ is surjection, so $\pi_1(X)$ cannot be trivial.

- Note that the claim is not true if we have just $S^1 \subset \bar{X}$. Indeed, you may take $X= \mathbb{R}^{2}- A$, where $A = B(0,1) \cup \mathbb{R}_{+}\times \{0\}$. This can be seen to be homotopy equivalent to a point.